# Name for string that holds array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, terminology

I am wondering what the proper name is for an array held in a string (string that holds an array).

Commonly used for storing tags or multiple variables in a database

EXAMPLE 1 (Image URLs for item):
`url1,url2,url3`

Example 2 (Video Tags): `tag1,tag2,tag3`

Example 3 (quests complete): `2,3,1,6,7,4`

These strings would get converted into an array with an explode in PHP usually.

**To clarify: What is the proper name for these types of strings?**

Comment: you could say "comma delimited string" or "comma separated string" ?

Comment: "soonToBeAnArrayString"

Comment: `comma separated string`

Comment: *"Insufficiently applied encoding practices which will break if your values ever happen to contain a comma"*. To serialise an array to a string, use established serialisation formats like `serialize` or JSON or such…

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are stored as `comma separated values` or `CSV`. This is a relatively common practice as a way to store multiple data points uder a single entry.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

> A comma-separated values (CSV) file is a delimited text file that uses a comma to separate values. A CSV file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text. Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas. The use of the comma as a field separator is the source of the name for this file format.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Except that I doubt OP applies actual CSV rules, like using quotes if values contain commas…